# Unable to use scp on Solaris

Tags: solaris, scp

I'm trying to use `scp` from one Solaris machine to another, but I get this message and the copy fails:

```
root@ark123 # scp -r emcgrab_SunOS_v4.4.4a.tar 192.163.119.21:/tmp
Password:
Sourcing /root/.profile-EIS.....
root@ark123
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it so `scp` will work?

Comment: please give the output of `scp -r -v emcgrab_SunOS_v4.4.4a.tar 192.163.119.21:/tmp`

Comment: Also, can you copy the file with another user? Using root is not the best practice.

Answer (score 3):

Tools like `scp` and `rsync` can get confused if your configuration files produce output even for non-interactive logins. Remove whatever prints out `Sourcing /root/.profile-EIS.....`. It's probably in your `~/.bashrc`: oddly, bash loads this file for non-login interactive shells *and* for non-interactive login shells whose parent is `rshd` or `sshd`.

Comment: Agreed.
I believe the `Sourcing /root/.profile-EIS` message is from an install back in the day with Sun's professional services team.  Chances are you should not need that file sourced.